# Launch watchOS2 app from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I have a simple interface with 3 buttons in iOS part (these should be shown on an iPhone, not on watches) and upon clicking on a button I want to set up a specific version of watch app (depending on button clicked, watch OS should use different data for its execution).

First I am not sure how to trigger watch app execution from iOS app part of the code. Second, I need to know how to pass the data about the button clicked. I read several tutorials on watchOS2, but they are talking mostly about how to make watch app, that is already running on apple watches, respond to events - that's not what I need. Are there any tutorials?

Could anyone, please, share some links/suggestion?

Comment: Why "-1"? I do not see any similar question neither on stackoverflow, nor can I find something like this just by googling it.

Answer (score 2):

You're dangling on the edge of Apple-acceptability, but here's how I'd do it:  Make your three apps.  With your iOS button, send a notification to the app which you want to open.  Within that notification have a button that allows the user to open the app.

Comment: I actually was able to solve the issue approximately how I wanted it by using `WCSession`. This tutorial helped me a lot: http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-tutorial-using-sendmessage-for-instantaneous-data-transfer-watch-connectivity-1/    I needed to implement it the other way round which is essentially the same.